# Informatica - Remove special Characters From xml target

Tags: java, xml, oracle, informatica

Im working in a project which we create hundreds of xml's in informatica everyday, and all the data which is in the xml should be filtered, like removing all kind of special characters like * +.. You get the idea.

Adding regular expressions for every field is too complicated and not possible due the large amount of mapping we have.

Any idea? 
Otherwise I'll go through all the xml files in java after creation to modify them.. Not a nice solution

Comment: Do u want a Java solution for "cleaning" your xmls or what?

Comment: Hopefully there will be some property i can add to the informatica to filter results.